# How to call a Javascript method with dynamic paramters depending on the table row?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with a few table rows. Each table row should call the reWrite() function with the table row number that is clicked. How is this possible? here my JS code:

```
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {
  document.write("<tr id='"+i+"'><td>");
  document.write(x[i].getAttribute('name'));
  document.write("</td></tr>");
  $("#"+i).click(function(){ reWrite(i); return false; });
  }
```

I can add a listener to each row in this loop. But the reWrite(i) does not work. How can I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: please don't use `document.write` unless you _really_ know what you're doing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    document.write("<tr id='" + i + "'><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getAttribute('name'));
    document.write("</td></tr>");
    (function (index) {
        $("#" + index).click(function () {
            reWrite(index);
            return false;
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Creating the generator function within the loop is an anti-pattern. Put the generator function *outside* the loop (or better yet, use the three other ways that are available here without using an additional function at all).

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because the function you're giving `click` has an *enduring reference* to the `i` variable, not a *copy* of it as of when you create the function. So when the click happens, regardless of which one it is, it sees the value of `i` **then** (which is probably `x.length`).

To fix it, the simplest thing in this *specific* case is to use the row's `id` property, since you're saving the information to the row:

```
$("#"+i).click(function(){ reWrite(this.id); return false; });
```

However, I'm a bit surprised that your code is working at all, because you're using invalid `id` values in a CSS selector. Although you can have `id` values starting with digits in HTML, they're not valid in CSS, and so the selectors you're using with `$()` (`#0`, `#1`, etc.) are invalid. jQuery is tolerating them for you (probably by accident because it optimizes those to calls to `getElementById`), but I would strongly advise not doing that.

---

Various other ways to solve the problem (rather than using the `id`):

1. Use the extra `data` argument jQuery lets you specify for the event:

   ```
   $("#"+i).on('click', i, function(e){ reWrite(e.data); return false; });
   ```
2. Make the click handlers close over a different thing than `i` that doesn't change:

   ```
   $("#"+i).on('click', i, buildHandler(i));

   //...outside the loop:
   function buildHandler(index) {
       return function() {
           reWrite(index);
           return false;
       };
   }
   ```
3. Use a `data-*` attribute on the row (but that's a lot like using the `id`).
4. Use an old-style `onxyz` handler as [suggested by techfoobar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16694003/157247) (but without the unnecessary `return false`, which [doesn't mean the same thing](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html) here as it does in jQuery):

   ```
   document.write("<tr id='"+i+"' onclick='reWrite("+i+");'><td>");
   ```

   I'm not a fan, but it's an option.

---

Finally: I'd advise not using `document.write` if you can possibly avoid it, and you nearly always can avoid it.

Comment: @Alnitak: Technically, yes, although browsers have always supported them in HTML (just not CSS).

Answer (score 1):

How about specifying the event handler inline using `onclick`:

```
document.write("<tr id='"+i+"' onclick='reWrite("+i+");'><td>");
```

*Side note*: The `</tr>` in that last `document.write("</td></tr>");` looks very wrong. You're ending the row after every `<td>`, without starting a row before.

Comment: A viable option. Note that you don't need the `return false`, because there is no default action for click on a `tr` and `return false` in a DOM0 handler [doesn't also stop propagation](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html) like it does in jQuery.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Yes, `return false` not needed in this case, old practices die slow.. :-)